# How is the message of the day printed on boot?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

Is there a binary that `cat`s some text from a file in `/etc` that's triggered off some upstart script/sysV init script?  I'm looking to cross compile whatever it may be for an embedded device for fun.

I've looked all over launchpad.net for the source but am unsure of what to look for.

Comment: Are you looking for /etc/motd? It's a plain-text file that can be edited to contain whatever message you'd like displayed.

Comment: my `/etc/motd` is not getting picked up.  i'm looking for what binary uses that file and prints it on boot or just how that file gets *used* in general?

Comment: The `/etc/motd` file is read and displayed by login. The `/etc/issue` file is read and displayed by getty.

Answer (score 3):

Before login, it is the /[etc/issue](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/issue.5.html) file that is shown.
After a login, it is [/etc/motd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/motd.5.html)

Comment: is this only on ssh-ing into the device?  what about just when the device comes up from a reboot?